# Slow MySQL with join query written in Laravel/Eloquent for Yajra DataTables

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-6, yajra-datatable

I am trying to pull the data from two tables by joining the data, but the sql query executed is dead slow. The idea is to pull all `users` and then combine with the `created_at` date from `points` table. Pulling all users or all points is rather quick, but having problems with writing a proper join sql. I did try to add indexes to appropriate columns (points.created_at for example), but those made query even slower.

This is the code that generates the query:

```
return $this->user
            ->query()
            ->select(['users.id', 'users.email', 'users.role', 'users.created_at', 'users.updated_at', 'pt.created_at AS last_transaction'])
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT points.user_id, points.created_at FROM points ORDER BY points.created_at DESC) AS pt'), 'pt.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('users.role', 'consument')
            ->groupBy('users.id');
```

Which generates this query:

```
select `users`.`id`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`role`, `users`.`created_at`, `users`.`updated_at`, `pt`.`created_at` as `last_transaction`
from `users`
left join (SELECT points.user_id, points.created_at FROM points ORDER BY points.created_at DESC) AS pt on `pt`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
where `users`.`role` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
group by `users`.`id`
order by `id` asc
```

Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'consument',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_verify_token` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84345 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Points table:

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tablet_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_company` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `points` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mutation_type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `points_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `points_company_id_foreign` (`company_id`),
  KEY `points_parent_company_index` (`parent_company`),
  KEY `points_tablet_id_index` (`tablet_id`),
  KEY `points_mutation_type_company_id_created_at_index` (`mutation_type`,`company_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `created_at_user_id` (`created_at`,`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `points_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `points_parent_company_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_company`) REFERENCES `parent_company` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `points_tablet_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tablet_id`) REFERENCES `tablets` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `points_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1798627 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Users has 84,263 and points has 1,636,119 rows. If I execute the query manually through phpMyAdmin, it takes about 150 seconds to execute. if I ran it through Laravel, page times out after 180 seconds.

I can add or remove indexes and change the sql query, but I can't change the database structure, so any help with optimized sql query would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there is is only one row per user in the points table you do the following:

If there is users which does not have a post in points you could use:

```
select `users`.`id`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`role`, `users`.`created_at`, 
`users`.`updated_at`, `pt`.`created_at` as `last_transaction`
from `users`
left join points AS pt on `pt`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
where `users`.`role` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
order by `id` ASC
```

If every user in the user table always has one post in the points table you could skip the left join and just:

```
select `users`.`id`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`role`, `users`.`created_at`, 
`users`.`updated_at`, `pt`.`created_at` as `last_transaction`
from `users`
join points AS pt on `pt`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
where `users`.`role` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null
order by `id` asc
```

Comment: I see I was not clear enough, sorry about that. Each user can have multiple rows in `points` table, that's why there's so many rows. And I need to get the latest entry date in `points` table per user, while listing all users.

Comment: Ok. I will make a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will return just one user and the latest point row based on the points column 'created_at'.

```
SELECT  `u`.`id`, 
        `u`.`email`, 
        `u`.`role`, 
        `u`.`created_at`,
        `u`.`updated_at`, 
        `pt`.`created_at` as `last_transaction`
from `users` u
LEFT join points AS pt on `pt`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) AS mm FROM points GROUP BY user_id
) AS m ON m.user_id = pt.user_id
where `u`.`role` = ? and `u`.`deleted_at` is NULL AND m.mm = pt.created_at
order by `id` ASC;
```